# Google Chrome Not Opening Since 25 January 2021 . .

Tags: google-chrome, startup

Two days ago I found that I couldn't open Google Chrome, my #2 browser.
Like all browsers opening, it began its spinner after double clicking on the app icon. Then after about 30 seconds, it just stopped.

I uninstalled and reinstalled via:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/g...rent_amd64.deb
--2021-01-24 12:13:53-- https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/g...rent_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 74.125.193.190, 74.125.193.91, 74.125.193.136, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|74.125.193.190|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 72800524 (69M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’

google-chrome-stable 100%[===================>] 69.43M 7.17MB/s in 10s

2021-01-24 12:14:07 (6.71 MB/s) - ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’ saved [72800524/72800524]

$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 259677 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (88.0.4324.96-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (88.0.4324.96-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

Then I tried starting Chrome from the CLI

```
$ google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 8: /usr/bin/readlink: Permission denied
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 10: /usr/bin/dirname: Permission denied
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: /usr/bin/cat: Permission denied
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: /usr/bin/cat: Success
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: /usr/bin/cat: Permission denied
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: /usr/bin/cat: Success
```

And nothing happens . . .

I copy below the lines 8 & 10 of /usr/bin/google-chrome:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2 #
3 # Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
4 # Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
5 # found in the LICENSE file.
6
7 # Let the wrapped binary know that it has been run through the wrapper.
8 export CHROME_WRAPPER="`readlink -f "$0"`"
9
10 HERE="`dirname "$CHROME_WRAPPER"`"
```

Not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when something interferes with Chrome's ability to read its cached files. What's odd is that this seems to be the result of something in Chrome itself, as the cached files are not something anyone will manually play with. You can test if this is the case by renaming/deleting the `~/.config/google-chrome` directory. For this exercise, let's just rename:

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome-old
```

Now start Chrome.

If this works, you'll notice that your preferences and bookmarks are "gone". If you sync these with Google, simply sign in again. If you keep them local, you will need to see if there are file permission differences between the new directory and the old one, make the necessary changes using `chown` and/or `chmod`, then copy some files back.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried it. Reinstalled and applied file move suggested. Exact same system response as before. Could it be something in Ubuntu that shuts down Chrome ?

Comment: I just installed the open-source version, Chromium via Snap. Seems to work fine. I installed Google Chrome via APT.

Comment: I see that Chromium suggests items from my Google searches done on Firefox. But why should I feel shocked by this ? Same old same old.

Comment: Also installed Brave browser https://brave.com/ . This is supposedly a more secure variant of Chromium with a nicer look.